# Data missed in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

Data missed a lot in logstash version 5.0,
is it a serous bug ,when a config the config file so many times ,it useless,data lost happen again and agin, how to use logstash to collect log event property ?

any reply will thankness

Comment: Please add more details in order to let the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash is all about reading logs from specific location and based on you interested information you can create index in elastic search or other output also possible.
Example of logstash conf

```
input { 
file {
# PLEASE SET APPROPRIATE PATH WHERE LOG FILE AVAILABLE
        #type => "java"
        type => "json-log"
        path => "d:/vox/logs/logs/vox.json"
        start_position => "beginning"
          codec => json
  }
 }

filter {
 if [type] == "json-log" {
   grok {
       match => { "message" => "UserName:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:UserName} -DL_JobID:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:DL_JobID} -DL_EntityID:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:DL_EntityID} -BatchesPerJob:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:BatchesPerJob} -RecordsInInputFile:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:RecordsInInputFile} -TimeTakenToProcess:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:TimeTakenToProcess} -DocsUpdatedInSOLR:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:DocsUpdatedInSOLR} -Failed:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:Failed} -RecordsSavedInDSE:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:RecordsSavedInDSE} -FileLoadStartTime:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:FileLoadStartTime} -FileLoadEndTime:%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:FileLoadEndTime}" }
       add_field => ["STATS_TYPE", "FILE_LOADED"]
    }

}
}
filter {

  mutate {
  # here converting data type

        convert => { "FileLoadStartTime" => "integer" }
        convert => { "RecordsInInputFile" => "integer" }




  }
}

output {
elasticsearch { 
# PLEASE CONFIGURE ES IP AND PORT WHERE LOG DOCs HAS TO PUSH

document_type => "json-log"
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        # action => "index"       
        # host => "localhost"
         index => "locallogstashdx_new"
        # workers => 1
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  #stdout { debug => true }
}
```

To know more you can go throw many available websites like
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/first-event.html